# Getting value of a CSS element

Tags: javascript, css, variables

Can anyone tell me what the problem with this snippet of JS is? I am trying to assign the value of 'container's margin-top to the m variable.

```
function test() 
{
  var e = document.getElementById('container');
  var m = e.style.getPropertyValue("marginTop");
  alert (m);        
}
```

edit: the alert was meant to display the value of m

Comment: is the value explicitly defined?

Comment: How does this `alert ('hi')` related to the question?!

Comment: sorry I meant it to be: alert(m);

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you write `"margin-top"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getStyle(elment, style) {
    var x = document.getElementById(element);

    if (x.currentStyle) {
      var y = x.currentStyle[style];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
      var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(style);
    }

    return y;
}

function test() {
    var m = getStyle('container', 'margin-top');
    alert(m);
}
```

Also, be careful with your variable scope. `m` won't be defined outside of `test()`.

Comment: Thanks, however alert message appears blank

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. `marginTop` is only defined if `margin-top` was explicitly set. Try this new version.

Comment: I cannot confirm your assumption. This is more likely related to the computed style. The `style` property only accesses the inline style.

Comment: Actually, your solution is wrong. Accessing `margin` is not equivalent to accessing `marginTop`, and the OP only wanted to assign the latter. You would have to *parse* the `margin` value, but I do not think this is necessary at all.

Comment: Functionality: If you want to allow hyphenated property names, you need to camelCase them for `currentStyle` and consider style-to-script property mappings. Compatibility: Use the MSHTML-proprietary way only as fallback, and try DOM Level 2 CSS shortcuts first, they are cheaper. Don't test `getComputedStyle` on `window` and call it on `document.defaultView`; test and call it on the latter. Style: Pass an object reference for first argument; that way the function is more flexible. DRY: http://PointedEars.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fdom%2Fcss.js (not perfect either).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this simple function:

```
function test() 
{
    var e = document.getElementById('container');
    var m = getStyle(e, "marginTop");
    alert ('hi ' + m);       
}

function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    else 
        var y = el.style[styleProp];
    return y;
}
```

Comment: That is *too* simple. `getPropertyValue()` only supports the hyphenated property name, and it should be `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` (and a more sophisticated feature test) to support Safari WebKit as well.